# C# LINQ - Get pairs, when second value is null in all pairs that have the same first value

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have pairs (in list) like this: [{a, 15}, {b, null}, {a, null}]

Each pair has a character key and a nullable value. I want to select all pairs where the list does not contain another pair with the same key and a non-null value.

In my sample list above I want to get {b, null} only, because 'a' has a non-null value in the first pair. How would I do that using LINQ?

Comment: So you want to get the first pair that has a value different to the one before it?

Comment: Did you mean you want to get {a, null}?

Comment: No, I'll show you another example, it should be clear then:
[{a, null}, {b, null}, {c, null}, {a, 6}, {d, 5}, {d, null}, {e, null}]
and I want to get {b, null}, {c, null}, {e, null}

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it

Comment: Does my answer match what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes @GlenThomas, that's exactly what I wanted, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Where` function to select the elements while using the `Any` function to check for the existence of pairs with the same key and non null values. Here is an example:

```
class Pair
{
    public char Key { get; set; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}

var pairs = new[] { new Pair { Key = 'a', Value = 15 },
                    new Pair { Key = 'b', Value = null },
                    new Pair { Key = 'a', Value = null }
}

var nullOnlyPairs = pairs.Where(p => !pairs.Any(a => a.Key == p.Key && a.Value != null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say list (variable name items) is a collection as (chr,Id) then use following linq to get your result

```
        var result = (from t1 in items
                      group t1 by t1.chr into t2
                      where t2.Count(p => p.Id!= null) == 0
                      select new
                      {
                          chr = t2.Key,
                          Id  = t2.Select(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault()
                      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your List item has two fields (Key, Value), you could do this.

```
var output = items.GroupBy(c=>c.Key) // Group by Letter
                  .Where(c=>!c.Any(e=>e.Value != null)) // Verify each Key has any other value than Null
                  .Select(c=>c.First());
```